# not to lose in the url parameter to go to another state int ANGULAR

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I'm sending a variable ($stateParams) in the url, to go to another template, I wonder if there is a way to go to the previous template that I visited, obtaining prior to the url and the parameter.

for example i go to the template1 to template2

```
url of template1: localhost:8100/index/PARAM
url of template2: localhost:8100/index/otherTemplate
```

if I return to template2 to template1, this URL appear

```
localhost:8100/index/
```

i loss the parameter..
they are my states

```
.state('index', {
  cache:false,
  url: '/index/:PARAM',
      templateUrl: 'templates/index.html',
      controller: 'indexAppController'
})

.state('otherTemplate', {
  url: '/otherTemplate',
      templateUrl: 'templates/template2.html',
      controller: 'templateAppController'
})
```

the parameter is lost when I go back to the previous template. this is my problem

Comment: This doesn't make sense without a lot better description of how you are navigating and some configuration code

Comment: @charlietfl is an example..You understand what I'm saying

Comment: No, I don't. I wouldn't have asked for clarification if I did. Suggest reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @charlietfl NOW IS MORE CLEAR? Please bear with me. I do not speak English well hehe. you can help?. I updated details.

Comment: Are you reloading the page? Are you using `html5Mode()`? I understand language is difficult but there are translation tools also. It's hard to help without understanding what is really happening and how things are being changed.

Comment: @charlietfl I'm just going from one state to another. I'm template2.html and I have a button with a hyperlink to return to index.html. Clicking on the button will load index.html but the parameter is lost. index.html has certainly false cache.You should always have it. What can I do?

Comment: OK...starting to understand a bit. Consider that if your navigation had been using browser back button the param would be there. That's why it was confusing. What about using `$window.history.back()`. Or store the last param?

Comment: @charlietfl I just want to return to the previous url. including parameter. ie if I am in template2.html and click on the button, I should go to this url index/PARAM. I am new to angular and ionic, then I would appreciate if I can explain it is to put code you put.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your parameters are asign as routeparams,

$routeParams.parameter_name="";

Note: Don’t forget to inject $routeParam parameter in controller. Otherwise you wont be able to use it.

sampleApp.controller('indexAppController', function($scope, $routeParams) {

});

Answer (score 0):

Why not add url parameter and value in local storage and use stateprovider for routing... using $state.go('state');